# Add BCC in Shipment Email Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, email, shipment

> Is there any **Event or Observer** to Add `BCC` in **Shipment Email**
>   **Programmatically**

Task Is Shipment Mail Send **2 Person** `1st is customer` and `2nd is dynamic email`

Please Provide me Suggestion How To Add `Programmatically` **BCC** in Shipment Email ?

**How Can I Do This ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it in configuration

- On the Admin Panel, Stores > Settings > Configuration.
- On the left panel, under Sales tab, click on Sales Emails subtab.
- Open the shipment section
- Add email or comma separated email in 'Send Shipment Email Copy To'

If you want to customise this beyond configuration you are changing this:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Email/Container/ShipmentIdentity.php#L40-L47

So observer or plugin (Interceptor) - not event.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html

Here is a suggestion on how to go Plugin Route

Xigen\Override

etc/di.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\ShipmentIdentity">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Xigen_Override_Plugin_Magento_Sales_Model_Order_Email_Container_ShipmentIdentity" sortOrder="10" type="Xigen\Override\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\ShipmentIdentity"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

`Plugin/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Email/Container/ShipmentIdentity.php`

```php
namespace Xigen\Override\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container;

class ShipmentIdentity
{

    public function afterGetEmailCopyTo(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\ShipmentIdentity $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        //Your plugin code
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to add bcc Programmatically

Comment: Try plugin route

Comment: please explain how to use plugin route

Comment: I have updated answer

Comment: i will check and update soon

Comment: 1+ for response

Comment: i can not get order object using this plugin

Comment: thank you its working

Answer (score 1):

you can use this event "email_invoice_set_template_vars_before" and you can also find more events here :

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/use-event-magento-2

Comment: please explain briefly and i want to add bcc in shipment email

Comment: as per my task shipment mail send 2 person 1st is customer and 2nd is dynamic email so how can i do this ?? check my updated answer

Comment: 1+ for response

Answer (score 1):

You can managed to work it by following code:

**Step 1**: Create a module with name **Vendor_Module** and do the following changes.

**Step 2**: create **di.xml** under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender" />
</config>
```

**Step 3**: Create **SenderBuilder.php** under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Order/Email/Sender/ShipmentSender.php

with content:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Email\Sender;


class ShipmentSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender
{

    public function send(Shipment $shipment, $forceSyncMode = false)
    {
        //do your logic
    }
}
```

And then run required commands 
`bin/magento setup:upgrade`
`bin/magento setup:di:compile`
`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
`bin/magento cache:clean`.
You can modify the codes according to your requirement.

**Note: Above codes are not Tested but it should work.**

Comment: i will check and update soon

Comment: as per my task shipment mail send 2 person 1st is customer and 2nd is dynamic email so how can i do this ?? check my updated answer

Comment: 1+ for response